# Why should I use novalidate rather than deleting validation tags?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, validation

It's easy to find answers what the `novalidate` attribute does in HTML5.
In `Angular.JS` [we get teached](http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/level/3/section/3/video/1) that we should use it, because `Angular.JS` should do the validation.
But why not just delete any validation tags instead?

[Example](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/11-novalidate.html?num=4):

```
<form novalidate>
  <input type=number name=num step=5>
</form>
```

Here I disable the build in `step=5` order with `novalidate`.
But why should I write both when I don't want do have it like that?

Isn't that the better approach?:

```
<form>
  <input type=number name=num>
</form>
```

So why use the `novalidation` field at all?

Comment: it disables html5 validation built into browsers.

Comment: Can you give me any source for that?

Comment: Are you sure that you read my question and did understand it?
Especially my example I posted does exactly that.

Comment: @BerndErnst, Check my answer with reference as well for you to get clear understanding and share the AngularJS doc taught you to use novalidate in your question

Comment: @Oriol I don't want validation. So why I use validation tags (for example) like step=5 just to disable it with novalidate? Why not just leave out the validation tags and the novalidate tag aswell?

Comment: If someone asks me: How to disable validation?
People answer: Use novalidate.
I ask: Why not disable/delete all validation tags you don't want to have?

Comment: Maybe because it's more semantic. Or because (if you add `novalidate` with JS), it will fallback to native validation if JS is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

> If you don't add this attribute. there will two validation one is from browser another from angular

Refer the below URL what actually HTML5 validation do.
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

**novalidate: specifies that the element represents a form that is not meant to be validated by browser during form submission.**

There is one more attribute called **
For Example: Below is the HTML Form without `novalidate` attribute.

```
<form action="demo_form.php">
E-mail: <input type="email" name="user_email" required="true">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

If you submit the below form, You will get the below browser inbuilt feature which validate the field.

[image]

> Note: The novalidate attribute of the form tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.

Reference URL:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/form.html#form.attrs.novalidate
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-formnovalidate
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp

Comment: So why I should use novalidate if I could instead just leave out the: required="true"?

Comment: share the AngularJS doc taught you to use novalidate in your question

Comment: http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/level/3/section/3/video/1 @Venkatraman

Comment: Video clearly says "Turn off Default html validation". watch it carefully. refer AngularJS Doc rather reference videos. BTW, this attribute will disable default feature from the browser then its up to any framework to control the validation. if you don't add this attribute. there will two validation one is from browser then is from Angular